# Using Scriptlet code inside frontend javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

im a student, not too experienced with coding. trying to make a software solution for my class, and having some problems with running <%...%> tags inside functions that are in  tags in an ejs HTML file.

```
    <script>
//grab elements
const textBox = document.querySelector(".lineBox");
const nextLine = document.querySelector(".nextLine");
const prompt = document.querySelector(".question");


//display starting script line
textBox.innerHTML = "<%= JSON.stringify(scripts[scriptName][counter][0]) %>";


//nextline function
function updateLine() {
<% counter = counter + 1; %>
if ("<%= JSON.stringify(scripts[scriptName][counter][0]) %>" == 1) {
  <% counter = counter + 1; %>
}
textBox.innerHTML = "<%= JSON.stringify(scripts[scriptName][counter][0]) %>";

}
//prompt line function
function promptLine() {
<% counter = counter + 1; %>

textBox.innerHTML = "<%= JSON.stringify(scripts[scriptName][counter][0]) %>";



}
//call functions onclick
nextLine.onclick = updateLine;
prompt.onclick = promptLine;
</script>
```

I am currently making a website that displays lines off a script for actors to learn. The problem is that the scriptlet tags are running regardless of the functions. My first thought was to put the whole function inside scriptlet tags, but unfortunately that means that I cant use the variables from the frontend ejs file like textBox and prompt inside those tags because that runs in the server side.

I don't have a lot of knowledge about this so I'm sure I'm wrong on something here. Any tips?

Comment: The server-side code (stuff inside <% %> tags) is not invoked by javascript clicks.  It executes only when the page first loads.  once the page is loaded that script no longer exists.  any communication between your javascript code to the server code has to be done via a new request to the server, either ajax or otherwise.

Comment: thanks james, could you perhaps give me an example?